# JavaScript global settings

Tags: javascript

In the following JavaScript code I always get `return 'http://address1/'` regardless of whether I set DEBUG: false, or DEBUG: true.

How come?

Is there a better way to write global app settings?

```
var globalSettings = {
  DEBUG: false,
  BASE_URL: function() {
    if (globalSettings.DEBUG = true) {
      return 'http://address1/'
    } else {
      return 'https://address2/'
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: `globalSettings.DEBUG`... In your code, `DEBUG` references the `DEBUG` field on the global object (be it `window` in a browser or `global` in Node), not the one you've set. Also, you are using the wrong operator for comparison.

Comment: That's a good idea. But it still always gives the first address. I've edited my post based on your comment as your comment seems closer to correct than my code.

Comment: As the answer states (and that is why this question is closed), you are using the wrong operator for comparison.

Comment: @Kyll `this.DEBUG` should also work right?

Comment: @PhilippSander Yes, if strictly called as `globalSettings.BASE_URL()`. `this` being dynamic and bindable, it's kind of less safe.

Comment: @Kyll well.... how else are you supposed to call it?

Comment: @PhilippSander You could, for example, write `getURL = globalSettings.BASE_URL`. If you execute `getURL()` then `this` would refer to the global context (or whatever other context `getURL` is bound to...).

Comment: @Kyll that's true! thanks for explaining :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use == for comparing values

= give a variable or field new value and checks it afterwards

You also don't need to check `== true`

also make sure to be in the right scope: use `globalSettings.DEBUG` instead of `DEBUG`.

```
var globalSettings = {
  DEBUG: false,
  BASE_URL: function() {
    if (globalSettings.DEBUG) {
      return 'http://address1/'
    } else {
      return 'https://address2/'
    }
  }
};
```